# How to useEffect pause setTimeout on handleMouseEnter event. Continue setTimeOout on handleMouseLeaveEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how i can use the handleMouseEnter/Leave event to pause/continue the setTimeout. The rest of the code appears to be working fine for me.

```
function Education({ slides }) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length;
  const timeout = useRef(null);
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const nextSlide = () => {
      setCurrent((current) => (current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1));
    };
    timeout.current = setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);

    return function () {
      if (timeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
      }
    };
  }, [current, length]);

  function handleMouseEnter(e) {
    setIsHovering(true);
    console.log("is hovering");
  }
  function handleMouseLeave(e) {
    setIsHovering(false);
    console.log("not hovering");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you can do this by this simple implementation.

```
const {useEffect, useState, useRef} = React;

const Education = () =>  {

    const slides = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length;
  const timeout = useRef(null);
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const nextSlide = () => {
      setCurrent((current) => (current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1));
    };
    if ( !isHovering)
        timeout.current = setTimeout(nextSlide, 2000);

    return function () {
      if (timeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
      }
    };
  }, [current, length, isHovering]);

  function handleMouseEnter(e) {
    // stop the timeout function to be set
    setIsHovering(true);
    // clear any existing timeout functions
    if ( timeout.current ){
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }
  }
  function handleMouseLeave(e) {
    // to trigger the useeffect function
    setIsHovering(false);
  }
  
  return(
  <div>
    { 
slides.map( (s, i) => {
    if ( i === current){
    return <div key={i} style={{padding:"2em", backgroundColor:"gray", fontSize:"2em"}}
    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
    onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >{s}</div>
  }
})
    }
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Education />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

You can check out in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thesyncoder/12q8r3ex/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i was looking for!